# How to generate random time in SAS and get time difference?

Tags: random, time, sas, generator, difference

I am very new to SAS Programming. I have to create two variables for working hour calculation. I also have to use random time for this task. Here is what I have tried...

```
DATA wh;
in_1 = 28800;
in_2 = 36000;
out_1 = 18000;
out_2 = 25200;

DO i=1 TO 5;
  time_in = RAND("UNIFORM", in_1, in_2);
  time_out = RAND("UNIFORM", out_1, out_2);

  working_hour = INTCK('HOUR', time_out, time_in);
OUTPUT;
END;
RUN;
```

The random time generator works fine, but the INTCK function does not return expected values. I know it may be very silly. But I am stuck :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what you are expecting.  The *time in* is random between 8:00 and 10:00, yet *time out* is random between 5:00 and 7:00.  Normal time frame computation of in to out would be a negative result!  However, your use of arguments in `INTCK` are reversed, so there is that.

Consider this sample code and output.

What changes to output would you expect ?
Specifically, would you want `1` for row 4 ? (6:43 to 8:39 is not two complete hours, yet INTCK with default arguments calculates two hours as from 6:00 to 8:00)

The code uses time literals so the random time range edge points are more friendly to human readers.

```
data have;
  call streaminit (2021);

  do time_clock_entry_id = 1 to 5;
    time_in  = rand("uniform", '05:00:00't, '07:00:00't);
    time_out = rand("uniform", '08:00:00't, '10:00:00't);

    working_hours = intck('hour', time_in, time_out);
    output;
  end;

  format time_in time_out time8.;
run;
```

[image]

Comment: Actually, I solved it. My time range was wrong. I changed the out_1 and out_2 values and it worked fine. Anyway, Thank you so much for your response.